# Issues on transferring physical machine to virtual

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v

EDIT - after initial problems, I moved on and have some success, but I still can't boot the machine.

I have trouble transferring old 2012 server to virtual.

The server is on GPT disk, EFI.

What I did:

1. created VHDX from the 2012 machine, using converted Disk2VHD also mounting boot partition using this https://www.bostonit.com/knowledge-base/there-are-blocking-issues-for-the-physical-to-virtual-conversion-there-is-no-bcd-boot/
2. created a new virtual machine Gen 2 on the Hyper-V host (Gen 1 didn't work)
3. fed the new machine with the VHDX and tried to boot it

What I got is that system runs Hyper-V boot circle, and then fails.  Then I get boot recovery options.

I then set no restart on error, and got INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE?

Tried to repair bcd, but no success.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before asking Serverfault, [ask the internet](https://www.veeam.com/blog/how-to-convert-physical-machine-hyper-v-virtual-machine-disk2vhd.html) (found with [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=create+VHDX++from+windows+server&ia=web)). The article raises the generation question mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I was trying different combinations of cloning procedure for hours before I asked for help. If I could easily fix this with search, I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: The problem is, you are bound to get answers that you have tried already, since nobody knows what you have tried so far.

Comment: I would even say "everything" :-) It seems that MS VM conversion is having issues with EFI. I am just trying to figure this out. Updated Q.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Generation 1 VM instead of Generation 2, see : [Should I create a generation 1 or 2 virtual machine in Hyper-V?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/should-i-create-a-generation-1-or-2-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v) because your old server was probably not using UEFI.

> We recommend that you create a generation 2 virtual machine to take
> advantage of features like Secure Boot unless one of the following
> statements is true:
>
> The VHD you want to boot from is not UEFI-compatible.
> [...]

Comment: I did try, but I will try again tomorrow. I even tried Microsoft Virtual Machine Creator plugin on the destination machine, but that too failed miserably. :(